# iPhone app- How to upload image to .net C# WCF?

Tags: c#, .net, iphone, wcf

I have a WCF service that my iPhone app is connected to. Now I need to add an upload photo feature to my iPhone app. That said, I needed to have my WCF service to accept Images and save it to my server. Any idea how to achieve this?

I did googling for some possible solutions but neither of them works for me.

Your responses is greatly appreciated.

Comment: what does the WCF service look like? Doing a HTTP Post from iphone in simple, understanding what to post to is the hard part.

Comment: The iPhone app will POST a request and my WCF will process it and return an JSON object- This works fine in most scenarios. But this one is different, I need my WCF to accept image file. So my iPhone app will upload an image file to my webserver and my WCF should be able to process the request.

Comment: what are the parameters for the POST?

Comment: byte array--> This is the image. But this wont work. If you have a better suggestion that would be great.

Answer (score 2):

sample code snippet, no error checking just basic code for posting image

```
// get image from somewhere...
NSData *imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 90);

NSString *urlString = @"http://yourserver.com/upload_image";

NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init] autorelease];
[request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlString]];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
NSMutableData *postBody = [NSMutableData data];

//add image data to POST
[postBody appendData:[NSData dataWithData:imageData]];

[request setHTTPBody: postBody];

// connect to the web
NSData *respData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:nil error:nil];
NSString *respStr = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:respData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

Comment: @samer 1) that is a different question and 2) you said you already had the WCF service? I would suggest you post that question and accept this one.

Comment: Yes I did but in my question I stated that I needed my WCF service to accept image from my iphone app. I already have the same code that you posted above(Not exactly the same but will do uploading of image). Sorry I can't accept your answer.

Answer (score 0):

I use the ASIHTTPRequest client library for my iPhone apps (http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/). Uploading a file with this library is trivial. If you can configure your services to accept vanilla posts for file uploads, you're done.

Comment: What do you mean? I don't quiet understand. Can give me a brief example please?

Comment: Can I use byte[] on my WCF method? and use ASIHTTPRequest to send the image file?

Comment: When you make a POST with file data with ASIHTTPRequest it does the exact same thing a browser with <form action="whatever" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data"> would do. On the server side you can handle the POST as you would normally do.

Comment: I am also getting image in form of Nsdata from iphone app,but dont know how to recieve it and save it on a directory.
I am adding product details with product image form iphone app to web app through wcf service call.
so recieving image from iphone app in nsdata and want to save that image into directory.

Answer (score 0):

it took me to much time to get, but here is the WCF part for all the people out there...

Interface (Iservice1.cs):

```
    [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(Method="POST", UriTemplate = @"/FileUpload/")]
    void FileUpload(Stream stream);
```

Implementation (Service1.svc.cs):

```
public string FileUpload(Stream stream)

{
    byte[] buffer = new byte[10000];
    stream.Read(buffer, 0, 10000);
    FileStream f = new FileStream("C:\\temp\\sample.jpg", FileMode.OpenOrCreate);
    f.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
    f.Close();
    stream.Close();
    return "Recieved the image on server";
}
```